# Como o método sort funciona?

Tags: javascript

Estou começando a aprender javascript e enquanto procurava exemplos de sort me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
numeros.sort(function (a, b) {
   return (a % 2 !=0);
});

console.log (numeros);
```

a saída do console ficou assim:

```
(10) [2,4,6,8,10,9,7,5,3,1]
```

eu só queria entender o que o sort fez para chegar nesse resultado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função `.sort` deve sempre retornar números. Negativo, positivo ou zero. Ou seja essa função está mal desenhada.

A [especificação é clara](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> returns a **negative value** if x < y, **zero** if x = y, or a **positive value** if x > y

Porem, e sem garantir que esse comportamento será o mesmo em todos os browsers (visto ela não dar o retorno esperado), o que se passa é:

Imagina este sort:

```
[true, false, false, true, true].sort((a, b) => a != b)
```

o resultado é

```
[false, false, true, true, true]
```

No caso de `a % 2 !=0` que basicamente é uma condição que dá `true` se o numero for ímpar o `.sort` vai dar prioridade aos resultados que derem `false` ficando assim resolvido o inicio do resultado `2,4,6,8,10` e depois o resto.

Se juntarmos um `console.log` percebermos porque os ímpares ficam invertidos:

```js
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
numeros.sort(function(a, b) {
  console.log(b, '>', numeros.join(','));
  return (a % 2 != 0);
});
```

ou seja, à medida que a array é iterada o numero ímpar de index *N* fica em segundo lugar, e na proxima iteração esse anterior ímpar de index *N* é empurrado para a direita pelo noo ímpar.

Comment: Só fortalecendo a resposta do Sergio: não é possível ordenar pedra, papel e tesoura. A ordenação computacional exige que se `a > b > c`, necessariamente `a > c`. Mas isso não se aplica a pedra, papel e tesoura, onde `pedra > tesoura > papel > pedra`

Answer (score 5):

A função `sort` de `Array` ordena o array com base na função passada. A documentação diz que se na função o valor retornado for menor que `0` então o valor `a` vai para o inicio, caso contrário `a` vai para o fim.

No seu caso acontece que está a testar se `a` é impar com:

```
return (a % 2 !=0);
```

Que irá dar `false` se for par e `true` se for impar, que lhe está a colocar os pares primeiro. Para respeitar o retorno numérico esperado para a função `sort` pode transforma-lo em:

```
return (a % 2);
```

Que já irá retornar um numero positivo caso o seja impar ou `0` caso seja par:

```js
var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
numeros.sort(function (a, b) {
   return (a % 2);
});

console.log(numeros);
```

Esta função é no entanto mais util para comparar objetos, em que consegue indicar as regras de comparação destes, que por sua vez forçam a ordenação:

```js
const pessoas = [
  { nome : "Claudio", idade : 22 },
  { nome : "Marta", idade : 19 },
  { nome : "Roberto", idade : 38 },
  { nome : "Jessica", idade : 27 }
];

let pessoasPorNome = pessoas.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.nome > b.nome;
});

console.log("Pessoas por nome:",pessoasPorNome);

let pessoasPorIdade = pessoas.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.idade > b.idade;
});

console.log("Pessoas por idade:",pessoasPorIdade);
```

[Documentação para a função sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)