# Explicação sobre a função e aplicação da função sort do javascript

Tags: javascript, classificação

Sei para que serve a função abaixo (retornar o candidato com maior números de votos), mas não entendo o funcionamento da função `sort`, passando um outra função.

Alguém sabe explicar e/ou onde encontrar material em português para esse forma de programação?

```js
candidates = [
    {name: "Mr. Black", votes: 140},
    {name: "Mr. White", votes: 135},
    {name: "Mr. Pink", votes: 145},
    {name: "Mr. Brown", votes: 13}
];

var candidatesSorted = candidates.sort(function (a, b) {

    return b.votes - a.votes;
});
console.log(candidatesSorted[0]);
```

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 3):

O sort() ordena os elementos de um array. Essa ordenação é de acordo com a tabela de código unicode.

Sintaxe `arr.sort([funcaoComparar])`

Se `funcaoComparar` não for informada, os elementos serão ordenados de acordo com a sua conversão para texto.

Exemplo: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].sort()`

resultado `[1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

> “10” veio antes do “2” porque “1”, que é o primeiro caractere de “10”, vem antes do “2”

**No seu caso trata-se de ordenação por números**

> Quando o parâmetro `funcaoComparar` é informado, o array será ordenado de acordo com o seu valor de retorno.

- Tipos de retorno:

  ```
  se a comparação for menor que zero, a é posicionado antes de b
  se a comparação for maior que zero, a é posicionado depois de b
  se a comparação for igual a zero, a e b permanecem com as posições inalteradas
  ```

**Exemplo**

```js
var arr = [5, 3, 1, 4, 2];

console.log('Array original:', arr);

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});

console.log('Array ordenado:', arr);
```

O que acontece é que o sort() pega o array original, compara dois valores e os muda de posição de acordo com essa comparação, logo em seguida ele pega novamente dois valores e os compara pra rearranjá-los de novo, e faz isso até que todo o array esteja ordenado.

Pegando o exemplo acima, onde usamos a - b, a ordenação acontece da seguinte forma: se o primeiro elemento comparado, no caso a, for maior que b, a subtração a - b resulta em um valor maior que zero, então a é posicionado depois de b (de acordo com as regras). Essa mesma lógica aplicada repetidamente no array, que está sendo modificado, faz que com que os valores maiores sejam posicionados mais ao fim do array, ou seja, faz a ordenação em ordem crescente!

```
var arr = [5, 3, 1, 4, 2];

compare(5,3); // retorna 2, 3 é posicionado na frente de 5
[3, 5, 1, 4, 2]

compare(3,1) // retorna 2, 1 é posicionado na frente de 3
[1, 3, 5, 4, 2]

compare(1,4) // retorna -3, nada muda

compare(1,2) // retorna -1, 3, nada muda

compare(3,5) retorna -2 e compare(3,4) retorna -1 nada muda

compare(3,2) // retorna 1, 2 na frente de 3
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]

compare(5,4) // retorna 1, 4 na frente de 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> A mesma lógica se aplica para ordenação decrescente, b - a, só que agora com os valores trocados de lugar faz com que a ordenação seja ao contrário da anterior

**Exemplo**

```js
var arr = [5, 3, 1, 4, 2];

console.log('Array original:', arr);

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
});

console.log('Array ordenado:', arr);
```

[mais sobre "Como o método sort() funciona"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248356/como-o-m%C3%A9todo-sort-funciona)

Answer (score 3):

Pensando em ordenação de maneira genérica, existem [vários algoritmos diferentes](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms) (cada um [com suas particularidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353853/112052)), mas uma coisa todos têm em comum: em algum momento, eles precisam comparar dois elementos e decidir qual será colocado antes e qual será colocado depois (afinal, "ordenar" é colocar os elementos em uma determinada ordem, seguindo alguma regra de ordenação).

É para isso que serve a função passada para o método [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Ela recebe dois parâmetros (no caso, `a` e `b`), e decide se, no resultado final (no array ordenado), `a` estará antes ou depois de `b`. Isso é definido pelo retorno desta função:

- se `a` deve estar antes de `b`, o retorno deve ser um número negativo (menor que zero)
- se `a` deve estar depois de `b`, o retorno deve ser um número positivo (maior que zero)
- se tanto faz a ordem entre eles, o retorno deve ser zero

Vendo a função que você usou:

```
function (a, b) {
    return b.votes - a.votes;
}
```

Supondo que `a.votes` seja 140 e `b.votes` seja 135, o retorno da função será `-5` (um número negativo). Ou seja, neste caso, `a` estará antes de `b` no resultado final.

Se `a.votes` for 13 e `b.votes` for 140, o retorno da função será `127` (um número positivo). Então neste caso, `a` estará depois de `b` no resultado final.

E se os valores de `a.votes` e `b.votes` forem iguais, a função retorna zero, indicando que neste caso tanto faz a ordem entre eles.

De maneira geral, sempre que `a.votes` for maior que `b.votes`, o resultado será negativo e `a` estará antes de `b` (os elementos com os maiores valores de `votes` estarão antes dos elementos com valores menores).

Em outras palavras, o resultado final é um array com os candidatos em ordem decrescente de votos.

---

Esta função pode ter a lógica que você quiser, não se limitando a comparar um único campo.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que quero ordenar os candidatos pela ordem decrescente de votos, mas caso eles tenham o mesmo número de votos, o desempate é feito pela ordem alfabética do nome. A função ficaria assim:

```js
// Mr. Black e Mr. Pink tem o mesmo número de votos
candidates = [
    {name: "Mr. Black", votes: 140},
    {name: "Mr. White", votes: 135},
    {name: "Mr. Pink", votes: 140},
    {name: "Mr. Brown", votes: 13}
];

var candidatesSorted = candidates.sort(function (a, b) {
    // primeiro verifica a ordem decrescente dos votos
    let result = b.votes - a.votes;

    // se os votos forem iguais, desempata pela ordem alfabética do nome
    if (result === 0) {
        result = a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    }

    return result;
});

console.log(candidatesSorted[0]); // Mr. Black
```

Para comparar os nomes usei a [função `localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), que segue a mesma lógica de retornar -1, 0 ou 1, usando a ordem alfabética como critério para definir o que vem antes e depois (para mais detalhes, ver [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445795/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/555139/112052)).

---

Um local que possui documentação em português é a MDN (Mozilla Developers Network). A documentação da função `sort` está [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

ps: muitas páginas não estão completamente traduzidas, mas no topo da página, ao lado direito, é possível mudar o idioma (e recomendo o inglês, já que não tem esses problemas de tradução).

Answer (score 1):

> [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
>
> ...
>
> **Sintaxe:**
>
> ```
> arr.sort([funcaoDeComparacao])
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Se o parametro funcaoDeComparacao é fornecido, o array será ordenado de acordo com o valor de retorno da funcaoDeComparacao. Considerando que a e b são dois elementos sendo comparados, então:
>
> - Se funcaoDeComparacao(a, b) for menos que 0, ordena a para um índice anterior a b, i.e. a vem primeiro.
> - Se funcaoDeComparacao(a, b) retornar 0, deixa a e b inalterados em relação um ao outro, mas ordenado em relação a todos os outros elementos. Nota: O padrão ECMAscript não garante este comportamento, e, portanto, nem todos os navegadores (e.g. Versões do Mozilla anteriores a 2003) respeitarão isto.
> - Se funcaoDeComparacao(a, b) é maior que 0, ordena b para um índice anterior que a.
>     funcaoDeComparacao(a, b) sempre deve retornar o mesmo valor dado um par específico de elementos a e b como seus dois parametros. Se resultados inconsistentes são retornados, então a ordenação é indefinida.
>
> ...