# Colocar array de strings em ordem decrescente, case insensitive e considerando acentos

Tags: javascript, array, string, classificação, acentuação

Eu sei como ordenar com acento, o problema é quando essa ordem é decrescente.
O código abaixo deixa na ordem decrescente e compara letras maiúsculas:

```js
let nome=['João','alice','Julia','carla'];
nome.sort((a,b)=>{
    let x=a.toUpperCase();
    let y=b.toUpperCase();

    return x==y ? 0 : x>y?-1:1; 
});
console.log(nome);
```

Esse código abaixo ordena palavras acentuadas:

```js
let words=['pé','pato','ás','abelha'];
words.sort((a,b)=>{     
    return a.localeCompare(b);
})
console.log(words);
```

Minha dúvida é como juntar os dois códigos, uma função que compare os caracteres acentuados e coloque na ordem decrescente.

Comment: Olhe esta resposta,  talvez ajude https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445795/como-funciona-o-m%c3%a9todo-localecompare/446589#446589

Comment: Já tentou inverter a array após ordenar elas com o localeCompare? `words.reverse();`

Comment: CypherPotato
 Caracas e não é que deu certo. Eu pensei que ele ia embaralhar se fosse letras maiúscula, mas foi certinho o localeCompare parece que compara letras maiúsculas também.

Comment: @IvairQuirino dei uma resposta mais detalhada sobre isso.

Comment: Qual deveria ser o resultado? `["pé", "pato", "ás", "abelha"]`? Se for, não precisa inverter o array, dá pra resolver no próprio `sort`

Comment: Vou deixar uma resposta mais tarde pois agora me está complicado mas veja se ajuda: https://ideone.com/dlnWtX

Comment: @AugustoVasques Bastava fazer `Intl.Collator().compare(b,a)` (inverter `a` e `b`, a mesma ideia que fiz na minha resposta). Aliás, como já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445795/112052), `Collator` e `localeCompare` funcionam da mesma maneira, a única diferença é que o `Collator` [é mais performático](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#performance) caso precise fazer várias comparações

Comment: @hkotsubo, você tem razão, eu estava um pouco apressado e cometi o equivoco de multiplicar por -1.

Answer (score 9):

Ao contrário do indicado nos comentários e em outra resposta (que foi apagada), não precisa inverter o array. Basta trocar o `a` e `b` na comparação:

```js
let words = ['pé', 'pato', 'ás', 'abelha'];
words.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a));
console.log(words); // [ 'pé', 'pato', 'ás', 'abelha' ]
```

Ou seja, em vez de `a.localeCompare(b)`, basta trocar para `b.localeCompare(a)`, que a ordenação já será em ordem descrescente. Afinal, a ideia da função de *callback* passada para `sort` é que ela deve retornar um número negativo se o primeiro parâmetro (no caso, `a`) for menor que o segundo (`b`). Ao inverter a chamada (em vez de verificar se `a` é menor que `b`, vejo se `b` é menor que `a`), o resultado acaba ficando "invertido", e o resultado será o array ordenado em ordem descrescente.

---

Já para considerar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, não precisa de `toUpperCase`, pois o próprio `localeCompare` possui opções para configurar este comportamento. No caso, basta usar a opção `sensitivity`. De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#sensitivity), há vários valores diferentes para ter os mais diversos resultados:

| `sensitivity` | Diferencia acentos? | Diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas? | Exemplo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "base" | não | não | a = á a = A |
| "accent" | sim | não | a ≠ á a = A |
| "case" | não | sim | a = á a ≠ A |
| "variant" | sim | sim | a ≠ á a ≠ A |

Um detalhe importante é que a ideia de `localeCompare` é fazer comparações de acordo com as regras de determinado *locale* (conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445795/112052)). Ao não informar um *locale*, ele usa a implementação *default* do ambiente no qual o código está rodando (que pode ser o idioma configurado no *browser*/SO, por exemplo, mas vale lembrar que isso [varia conforme a implementação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146784)).

De qualquer forma, se quer uma ordenação específica, sugiro informar o *locale*. Por exemplo, se quer que a ordenação siga as regras da língua portuguesa do Brasil (já que também existem as regras de Portugal, entre outros), pode usar `'pt-BR'`. Lembrando que há diferenças no caso de ter letras maiúsculas, por exemplo:

```js
let locale = 'pt-BR';
let words = ['Ás', 'ás', 'Ás', 'joão', 'João'];
words.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a, locale));
// maiúsculas antes 
console.log(words); // [ 'João', 'joão', 'Ás', 'Ás', 'ás' ]

words = ['Ás', 'ás', 'Ás', 'joão', 'João'];
words.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a, locale, { sensitivity: 'base' }));
// minúsculas e maiúsculas são iguais, mantém a ordem em que estão no array
console.log(words); // [ 'joão', 'João', 'Ás', 'ás', 'Ás' ]
```

A regra padrão do *locale* `pt-BR` é colocar as maiúsculas depois (mas como está ordenando em ordem decrescente, "João" ficou antes de "joão"). Já se usarmos `sensitivity: 'base'`, o "J" e "j" passam a ser considerados a mesma letra, e [como a ordenação é estável a partir do ES2019](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort), eles ficam na mesma ordem em que estavam no array original. Ou seja, não precisa usar `toUpperCase`.

Aliás, como curiosidade, este é um caso em que usar `reverse` daria um resultado diferente:

```js
let locale = 'pt-BR';

let words = ['Ás', 'ás', 'Ás', 'joão', 'João'];
words.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a, locale, { sensitivity: 'base' }));
// minúsculas e maiúsculas são iguais, mantém a ordem em que estão no array
console.log(words); // [ 'joão', 'João', 'Ás', 'ás', 'Ás' ]

words = ['Ás', 'ás', 'Ás', 'joão', 'João'];
// ordenando em ordem crescente
words.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, locale, { sensitivity: 'base' }));
console.log(words); // [ 'Ás', 'ás', 'Ás', 'joão', 'João' ]
words.reverse(); // invertendo
console.log(words); // [ 'João', 'joão', 'Ás', 'ás', 'Ás' ]
```

Veja que `b.localeCompare(a, locale, { sensitivity: 'base' })` faz com que "joão" fique antes de "João" (pois o "j" e "J" são considerados iguais, e como a ordenação é estável, eles mantém a ordem em que estavam no array).

Agora, se trocarmos `a` e `b` no `localeCompare` (ou seja, ordem crescente), ocorre a mesma coisa ("joão" fica antes de "João", já que `sensitivity: 'base'` faz a comparação *case insentivive*). E depois, ao inverter o array, "João" passa a ficar antes de "joão".

Se não fizer diferença (e eu entendo que não faz, afinal, se a ordenação é *case insensitive*, tanto faz "João" estar antes ou depois de "joão"), ainda sim eu usaria a primeira opção, já que `reverse` acaba percorrendo o array mais uma vez, de forma desnecessária - para que fazer isso, se o `localeCompare` já retorna na ordem que precisa?

---

Comportamento similar pode ser visto com caracteres acentuados:

```js
let locale = 'pt-BR';
let words = ['as', 'ás', 'as', 'ás'];
words.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a, locale));
// maiúsculas antes 
console.log(words); // [ 'ás', 'ás', 'as', 'as' ]

words =  ['as', 'ás', 'as', 'ás'];
words.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a, locale, { sensitivity: 'base' }));
console.log(words); // [ 'as', 'ás', 'as', 'ás' ]
```

O *locale* `pt-BR` coloca as letras acentuadas depois das não-acentuadas (mas como é ordem decrescente, então os acentos vieram primeiro). Por isso no primeiro caso todas as ocorrências de "ás" vieram antes de "as".

Mas a opção `sensitivity: 'base'` faz com que não haja esta diferenciação (ou seja, `a` e `á` são consideradas a mesma letra), portanto elas mantém a ordem em que estavam no array original (desde que o seu *browser* já esteja de acordo com o ES2019, que garante que a ordenação é estável).

Você também poderia usar `caseFirst: 'lower'` para colocar as minúsculas primeiro, mudar o `sensitivity` de acordo com a tabela já informada acima, etc, enfim, `localeCompare` já te dá inúmeras opções para ordenar da forma desejada.

---

#### Resumindo...

Para a ordem em si, basta trocar o `a` e `b` de lugar (`a.localeCompare(b)` para ordem crescente, `b.localeCompare(a)` para decrescente), sem a necessidade de ficar invertendo o array. Quanto às demais regras (acentos, maiúsculas/minúsculas, etc), basta usar as opções de `localeCompare` (veja a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#options) para mais detalhes).

---

Por fim, você também pode usar um [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator), que funciona de maneira similar à `localeCompare` (inclusive, aceita as mesmas opções):

```js
let ordem = new Intl.Collator('pt-BR', { sensitivity: 'base' });

let words = ['pé', 'pato', 'ás', 'abelha', 'as'];
words.sort((a, b) => ordem.compare(b, a));
console.log(words);
```

A ideia é basicamente a mesma: `ordem.compare(a, b)` para ordem crescente, e `ordem.compare(b, a)` para decrescente. E para as regras de ordenação de maiúsculas/minúsculas, acentos, etc, use as opções já mencionadas.

A diferença é que, [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#performance), `Intl.Collator` tem desempenho melhor que `localeCompare` quando a quantidade de comparações a serem feitas for muito grande (por exemplo, se for ordenar um array com muitas strings). Mas o funcionamento das regras de ordenação são os mesmos.