# Como ordenar array com base em um array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Problema:

Estou tentando ordenar um array de boxes de acordo com as tags de forma que quanto mais tags compativeis mais em primeiro lugar ficara.

```js
tags = ['new', 'tech'];

boxes = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'tech ipsum',
    tags: ['watch', 'tech'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'apple ipsum',
    tags: ['new', 'tech', 'apple'],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'windows ipsum',
    tags: ['tech', 'apple'],
  },
];

boxes.map(box => {
  console.log(box);
  box.tags.includes(tags);
  console.log(box.tags.includes(tags));
});
```

Estou tentando resolver esse problema criando dois loops e percorrendo as tags e contando quantas combinacoes sao e dai eu salvo o index e ordeno no final, mas esta fora de ser um algoritmo aceitavel, tem alguma formula ou nome de algoritmo  para ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Este seria o resultado esperado:

```js
[{
  id: 2,
  name: 'apple ipsum',
  tags: ['new', 'tech', 'apple'],
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'windows ipsum',
  tags: ['tech', 'apple'],
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'tech ipsum',
  tags: ['watch', 'tech'],
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução interessante seria uma espécie de ranqueamento numérico.

Segue um exemplo

```js
const tags = ['new', 'tech'];

const boxes = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'tech ipsum',
    tags: ['watch', 'tech'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'apple ipsum',
    tags: ['new', 'tech', 'apple'],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'windows ipsum',
    tags: ['tech', 'apple'],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'linux ipsum',
    tags: ['new', 'linux', 'tech'],
  },
];

const boxRank = (objTags) => {
  /* Transforma o resultado em uma string */
  const n = objTags.map((tag) => {
    /* Identifica em qual posição do array de `tags` o item está. Se o resultado for maior que -1, retorna o index e acrescenta +1 para evitar o número 0 no ínicio. */
    const i = tags.indexOf(tag);
    
    return i > -1 ? i + 1 : 0;
  }).join('');
  
  /* Transforma em numérico */
  return parseInt(n);
};

const sortBoxesByRank = (a, b) => {
  if (boxRank(a.tags) > boxRank(b.tags)) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (boxRank(a.tags) < boxRank(b.tags)) {
    return 1;
  }
  
   return 0;
};

boxes.forEach((item) => {
   console.log('rank', item.name, boxRank(item.tags))
});

/* Ordena o array baseado no rank das tags de cada objeto */
boxes.sort(sortBoxesByRank);
```

Nesse exemplo, acrescentei mais um item para teste mas o resultado é o que você disse esperar:

```
[{
  id: 2,
  name: 'apple ipsum',
  tags: ['new', 'tech', 'apple'],
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'windows ipsum',
  tags: ['tech', 'apple'],
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'tech ipsum',
  tags: ['watch', 'tech'],
}]
```

Apenas não considera a ordem exata das tags, apenas a quantidade de ocorrência.

Para mais informações sobre como funciona o `sort`, tem algumas respostas boas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248363/210110).

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta! Única coisa que eu ajustaria é o "newBoxes = boxes.sort(...)" pois, de acordo com a documentação, o método sort não retorna uma nova array.

Comment: Falha minha, não é necessário atribuir a uma variável nova. Removido! Obrigada pelo aviso ✌️

Answer (score 3):

A melhor coisa é "dividir para conquistar". Vamos por partes.

Primeiro, criar uma função que conta a quantidade de "tags compatíveis" de uma caixa:

```
function matches(box, tags) {
  return box.tags.filter(tag => tags.includes(tag)).length;
}
```

Com ela pronta, podemos utilizar o método [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), passando uma função de comparação. De acordo com a documentação, essa função vai comparar todas as caixas, em duplas... Se o valor retornado pela função for negativo, ele vai colocar a caixa "A" antes da caixa "B". Se for positivo, vai colocar a caixa "A" depois da caixa "B".

Uma maneira fácil de fazer isso é subtrair a nossa quantidade de caixas compatíveis, assim, uma caixa "A" com 2 tags compatíveis vai vir sempre antes de uma caixa "B" com 1 tag compatível (pois 1 - 2 = -1, negativo):

```
boxes.sort((box1, box2) => matches(box2, tags) - matches(box1, tags));
```

Comment: Bem mais enxuto que a minha solução. +1 

Comment: Achei o seu `sortBoxesByRank` mais didático que o meu